# Cassandra - Average tombstones per slice is the same as Average live cells per slice

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

```
SSTable count: 2
    Space used (live): 66483
    Space used (total): 66483
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 740
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.20385198102497917
    Number of partitions (estimate): 698
    Memtable cell count: 238
    Memtable data size: 124636
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0
    Memtable switch count: 1
    Local read count: 6360
    Local read latency: 0.049 ms
    Local write count: 679
    Local write latency: 0.015 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bloom filter false positives: 2
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 608
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 592
    Index summary off heap memory used: 100
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 48
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 216
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 924
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 550
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Even though there are no tombstones ( I examined it using the sstablemetada and https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools), It says it always reads one tombstone?

I have ttls set to the data when I insert them. But the ttls are for 1 year and just started the services. So, it can't be because records expired.

Is there any other reason it always reads one tombstone.

Note: While inserting records I use if not exists. not sure if it has to do with anything.

EDIT: adding my schema definiton

```
CREATE TABLE items(
id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
data blob,
) WITH compaction = {
'compaction_window_size': '1',
'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS',
'class': 
'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'
};
```

Comment: What does your datamodel look like? Does it involve collection like set/list?

Comment: It just has an int64 partitionkey and a single blob column.I've edited the post to include the definition.